# Locality sensitive hashing with non-scalal values

Tags: algorithms, statistics, big-data

Locality sensitive hashing works well when matching is between vectors of scalars, but I now need to extend LSH to compare matrices. Each matrix is formed of *n* readings from *m* sensors forming a *n* by *m* matrix. Comparison between differing columns is inappropriate.

I could turn the matrices into vectors of length *n* * *m* and ensure permutations only occurred with blocks of length *n*. For example

[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
[7 8 9]

would map to

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

with the the units for permutation being [1 2 3], [4 5 6] and [7 8 9].

My first thought is that the restriction on permutation will weaken the statistical properties that LSH relies upon, but if *n* (the number of permutable items) is large enough compared to *m* (the size of each non-permutable items) the this will asymptotically disappear as a concern.

My other thought is to project the *n* * *m* matrix on to a vector of lower dimension which it is valid to permute, since each scalar in the vector encodes part of each column in the vector assuming *n* vectors of length *m* being projected onto a single vector of length *n* or less.

How could I achieve such a projection, without losing excessive information? Is it preferable over relying on the former's asymptotic behaviour?

Comment: How do you want to compare two matrices?  What notion of similarity do you have in mind?  Under what conditions do you want to consider two matrices to "match" each other?  Do you have a distance metric in mind?

Comment: The _m_ sensor outputs are the results from an FFT of an audio signal sampled _n_ times. The similarity metric for a vector is the Jaccard index |a-b|/|a+b| where |a-b| is the size of the intersection of the set formed from the vector's a and b, and like wise |a+b | is the size of the union. LSH uses a probabilistic approximation to the Jaccard index. This works easily for scalar values forming a and b, but what if the values are vectors so a &b form matrices between which the concept of distance is meaningless. So I need a vector approximation to each of a & b.

Comment: OK, that specifies a similarity metric for vectors.  Do you have a similarity metric for matrices?  That's the first step.  A LSH is locality-sensitive with respect to a particular distance metric, so you can't ask for such a hash function until you have decided on a similarity metric that, given a pair of matrices, determines how similar they are.

Comment: The best I can with for a non square matrix A is the vector of the eigenvalues of A Tanspose[A]. Slightly dissimilar matrices should  be similar, I think

Comment: That's not a similarity metric between matrices.  A similarity metric between matrices has the form $d(A_1,A_1) = \cdots$, i.e., it depends on *two* matrices.  Also, it is a number.  The vector of eigenvalues of $A A^\top$ doesn't qualify on either conditions; it doesn't depend on two matrices (it doesn't provide a way to compare two matrices), and it's not a single number.  I don't think your question is answerable until you can identify a similarity metric / distance metric between matrices.

Comment: See the Wiki on matrix diagonal decomposition. Similar matrices, for which there is a strict definition, do have similar eigenvalues diagonal matrices and if you consider the definition of an eigenvector matrices which are similar in a more conventional sense will have correspondingly similarity. So a Euclidean distance between vectors formed of eigenvectors of the same dimension may serve as a scalar measure of similarity. I need to some more work when I'm back in the office to confirm this, but I'm sure it is the case. The matrices obviously have to be square which requires A Transpose[A]

Comment: Now I'm concerned.  You say it may serve as a measure of similarity.  Well, sure.  There are lots of things that can serve as a measure of similarity, each with different properties.  The more important question is: is *that* the measure you want to use for comparing matrices?  If you're not sure or don't know, the question is not ready to be answered.  Once you know, please edit the question to specify that.